# Why do I get System.NullReferenceException when I use Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

My action is

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.returnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

In the view I defined model `@model OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel` and when I use helper `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName)` I get `System.NullReferenceException`.

Do I really need to pass an instance of my model in the action like `return View(new LoginModel())` when I would like to use `Html.EditorFor()`?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

When you use the `@model type` directive at the top of your view, you are telling the framework it can expect an instance of that type. The HTML helpers (e.g. `Html.DisplayFor`, `Html.EditorFor`, etc.) are all based on the type of model that you supply. You can see this if you open your view, and hover your mouse cursor over `EditorFor`. You'll see something like this:

```
string IHtmlHelper<OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel>.DisplayNameFor<string>(
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel, string>> expression)
```

Notice that the method is generic and is based on `OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel`. This is because these methods are expecting you to pass an instance of `OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel` to your view, as that's what you stated using the `@model` directive at the top of your view.

> No because I know what this exception means but I do not know why I get it in this particular situation. For example for Html.LabelFor it works fine.

The reason it works for `LabelFor` is because `LabelFor` is looking at metadata for your model, rather than needing an instance of it. By default, it simply creates a label with the name of the property you pass it. In your case, if you called `@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)` it will create a label HTML element whose text is `Username`, but it doesn't need an instance of your viewmodel to do that.

`EditorFor`, on the other hand, is both looking at metadata for your `Username` property, to create an appropriate input HTML element (e.g. a textbox for a string, or a checkbox for a bool), and also using the value of the `Username` property in order to populate that editor (e.g. checking the checkbox). That's why you get the exception when calling `Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username)` when you're not giving it an instance of your model.

Comment: @Qwertyluk `Html.LabelFor` will always work without a model, as long as you specify the `@model` directive in your view to tell the framework what your model type is. At that point, any call to `Html.LabelFor` will examine the model _type_ to determine what to render - it doesn't need an _instance_ of that type.

Comment: I also have the same code on the other machine and it works fine. It seems very strange why it works there.

Answer (score 2):

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#passing-data-to-views

> To provide the model to the view, the controller passes it as a parameter:

```
public IActionResult Contact()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

    var viewModel = new Address()
    {
        Name = "Microsoft",
        Street = "One Microsoft Way",
        City = "Redmond",
        State = "WA",
        PostalCode = "98052-6399"
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Check also the definition of view: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

You need to use a view with an object to return the data to the view. Be careful as a string alone is considered a view name.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, your action must provide an instance of your model the the view.

`@model OnlineShop.Models.ViewModels.LoginModel` informs the view to expect Model to be of that type and that it will be passed to the view by the controller. LoginModel being a class, it's default value is null.